# Cannot install gevent on Mac M1

Tags: python, apple-m1, gevent, macos-ventura

Cannot install gevent inside venv: on Mac M1 (OS Ventura 13.3.1 (22E261)), python 3.9

```
 Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/deps/c-ares"  && if [ -r include/ares_build.h ]; then cp include/ares_build.h include/ares_build.h.orig; fi   && sh ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking -C CFLAGS="-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code"  && cp src/lib/ares_config.h include/ares_build.h "$OLDPWD"   && cat include/ares_build.h   && if [ -r include/ares_build.h.orig ]; then mv include/ares_build.h.orig include/ares_build.h; fi) > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-cpython-39/c-ares/include
      configure: WARNING: Continuing even with errors mentioned immediately above this line.
      configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/deps/c-ares':
      configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
      See `config.log' for more details
      configure: creating cache config.cache
      checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
      checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
      checking whether to enable debug build options... no
      checking whether to enable compiler optimizer... not specified (assuming yes)
      checking whether to enable strict compiler warnings... no
      checking whether to enable compiler warnings as errors... no
      checking whether to enable hiding of library internal symbols... yes
      checking whether to expose internal static functions for testing... no
      checking for path separator... :
      checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
      checking for grep... /usr/bin/grep
      checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
      checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
      checking whether to build with code coverage support... no
      checking build system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.4.0
      checking host system type... aarch64-apple-darwin22.4.0
      configure: using CFLAGS: -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code
      configure: CFLAGS error: CFLAGS may only be used to specify C compiler flags, not macro definitions. Use CPPFLAGS for: -DNDEBUG
      checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
      checking for gcc... gcc
      checking whether the C compiler works... no
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/afedorc/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/afedorc/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/afedorc/Documents/project/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 496, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 362, in run_setup
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/normal/lib/python3.9/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 343, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build.py", line 131, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1244, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 144, in run
          base_class.run(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/setuptools_ext.py", line 144, in run
          base_class.run(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 84, in run
          _build_ext.run(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 467, in build_extensions
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-build-env-fbajzq10/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 493, in _build_extensions_serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/_setuputils.py", line 368, in build_extension
          self.gevent_prepare(ext)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/_setuputils.py", line 365, in gevent_prepare
          configure(self, ext)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/_setupares.py", line 80, in configure_ares
          system(ares_configure_command)
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/_setuputils.py", line 195, in system
          if _system(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs):
        File "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/_setuputils.py", line 191, in _system
          return check_call(cmd, cwd=cwd, env=env, **kwargs)
        File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(cd  "/private/var/folders/6j/khw733_d6w52dc93lqy5d0lc0000gq/T/pip-install-bhh121m3/gevent_efb4e03c299d4a319e3ec30bf24e59f5/deps/c-ares"  && if [ -r include/ares_build.h ]; then cp include/ares_build.h include/ares_build.h.orig; fi   && sh ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking -C CFLAGS="-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -iwithsysroot/System/Library/Frameworks/System.framework/PrivateHeaders -iwithsysroot/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Headers -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-error=unreachable-code"  && cp src/lib/ares_config.h include/ares_build.h "$OLDPWD"   && cat include/ares_build.h   && if [ -r include/ares_build.h.orig ]; then mv include/ares_build.h.orig include/ares_build.h; fi) > configure-output.txt' returned non-zero exit status 77.
      [end of output]
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: *"See config.log for more details"*…!?

Comment: It would be great if  you can advice me where I can find my config.log, I am a bit new to this